# How to do a single row query with Android Room

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

How do I make a single row query with Android Room with RxJava? I am able to query for List of items, no issues. Here, I want to find if a specific row exists. According to the docs, looks like I can return Single and check for EmptyResultSetException exception if no row exists.

I can have something like:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userId = :id LIMIT 1")
Single<User> findByUserId(String userId);
```

How do I use this call? Looks like there is some onError / onSuccess but cannot find those methods on Single<>.

```
usersDao.findByUserId("xxx").???
```

Any working example will be great!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> According to the docs, looks like I can return Single and check for EmptyResultSetException exception if no row exists.

Or, just return `User`, if you are handling your background threading by some other means.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userId = :id")
User findByUserId(String id);
```

> How do I use this call?

```
usersDao.findByUserId("xxx")
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(user -> { ... }, error -> { ... });
```

Here, I show `subscribe()` taking two lambda expressions, for the `User` and the error. You could use two `Consumer` objects instead. I also assume that you have `rxandroid` as a dependency, for `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`, and that you want the `User` delivered to you on that thread.

IOW, you use this the same way as you use any other `Single` from RxJava. The details will vary based on your needs.

Comment: Thanks! In the above example, User is not an observable right? then .subscribe() won't work right?

Comment: @srvy: In the example after the first quoted passage, the return value is `User`, and you need to make that `findByUserId()` call on a background thread. In the example after the second quoted passage, I am using your `Single<User>` edition of `findByUserId()`, which handles the background threading for you if you `subscribe()` on a background thread.

Comment: or You can use Maybe and use switchIfEmpty

Answer (score 0):

According to the Google docs: For single result queries, the return type can be any data object (also known as POJOs). For queries that return multiple values, you can use java.util.List or Array.
[Google docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Query)